# BringToFront isn't bringing form to the front

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to set up a button that does the following:

1. Checks to see if a form is open (and has lost focus). If so, it brings that form to the front.
2. If not, it opens a new instance of the form.

However, I've tried a few different methods and it will always either create a new form (if I use frm_About.visible as the check) or simply not do anything (with the following code).

```
Private Sub counter_aboutClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles counter_About.Click
    If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of frm_About).Any Then
        frm_About.BringToFront()
    Else
        Dim oAbout As frm_About
        oAbout = New frm_About()
        oAbout.Show()
        oAbout = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

I've heard that there's a bug with BringToFront in certain scenarios, am I hitting that bug?

Comment: I believe you need instance of `frm_About` to bring it to front. Looks like you are trying to call `BringToFront()` on the type

Comment: Hrm. frm_About is the name of the form, I'm not quite sure how to indicate a specific instance instead. Could I figure that out by debugging and just seeing what the call stack looks like when I've got that form open?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - welcome to the scourge of vb.net's default instances.

Comment: @J... strange.. strange language :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - yes, it's a particular headache with multithreaded code because the runtime will create a *separate* default instance of a form if it is merely referred to (by class name as default instance) from a different thread.  You can imagine the mess that creates...

Comment: Yeah, that is quite confusing. But iterating through each open form instance works, so I'm going to use that while I read up on default instances in VB.

Comment: @SeanLong - the call to `.Any` will iterate through the forms anyway so you might as well just do it yourself.  You can always break out, etc, if and when you find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB.Net does a terrible thing and creates a default instance of a form (which can be referred to by its class name).  This creates endless confusion and headaches - I suggest you read up on default instances (google can find a lot to read about, surely)

In this case, you have a class called `frm_About` as well as a default instance of that form which is also called `frm_About`.  If you've created a new form of type `frm_About` then the following code

```
If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of frm_About).Any Then
    frm_About.BringToFront()
```

will search your open forms to look for a form of type `frm_About` and, if it finds one, will attempt to bring the default instance of `frm_About` to the front - note that the open form can be (an in your case is most likely) not the default instance but any instance created with `New frm_About()`.

To find the actual instance of the form you would have to do something like :

```
For Each openForm In Application.OpenForms()
    If TypeOf (openForm) Is frm_About Then _
                                   CType(openForm, frm_About).BringToFront()
Next
```